# playsound and preferredsoundplayer - issues with sound?

Tags: python, loops, audio, terminal

I have created a small audio-file I want to loop over and over while my program is running it in a terminal/command line window without needing the user to have anything else installed. I came across the "playsound" library and have been trying to get it to work as expected without any luck. My goal is to play the sound in the background while the program is still running in the background (e.g "audiofile", 0 in both these cases) but using that argument will just result in silence, or if i loop it static weird noises like it's starting the same overlapping the other when looping. Also - using playsound, this method only seems to work under Windows, when I ran it under my ubuntu-machine it said that "Block=False is not supported by this platform" So just for testing i went for the synchronously route and now the audio works (kind of) while stopping the program until the sound is done playing.

This may be possible to bypass by running the loop in it's own thread or something but it gave me another problem instead, while the loop works in both of the codesnippets below, it adds a small delay of > 1sec after finishing the audiotrack and starting over witch is not what i want, and the audiofile itself is not any problem, if I loop the track over and over in audacity or similar it's a perfect loop, so the issue must be related to the loop itself. My original audiofile was in mp3-format and after some research on this I found that mp3-format may add a little bit of silence in the beginning in some cases and that wav is more recommended for loops, so I made wav-files instead but the same problems still occur.

playsound:

```
from playsound import playsound

def soundloop():
    while True:
        playsound("audio.wav", 1)

soundloop()
```

preferredsoundplayer:

```
from preferredsoundplayer import *

def soundloop():
    while True:
        soundplay("audio.wav", 1)
            
soundloop()
```

My hope is to be able to solve this either by "fixing" Block=0 in preferredsoundplayer (which is the only of these two that seems to support that even under Linux) or to somehow get rid of the small delay using the above method, and running the function in it's own thread to avoid the program to be stopped until it's looped one time. Thanks on beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
from preferredsoundplayer import *
mywave = loopsound("audio.wav")
myinput = input("Enter any key to close")
stoploop(mywave)
print("bye")
```